# How do I make a program that shows a simple loading screen? See below for more details

Tags: python, python-3.x, powershell

I wrote this -

```
import time

timeout = time.time() + 2

dot, i = ".", 0
while timeout > time.time():
    print ("Loading" + dot*i, end = "\r")
    time.sleep (0.1)
    if i == 3:
        i = 0
    else:
        i += 1
```

It runs fine till "loading...", then I need it to go back to "loading" and loop till the time expires.
PS - I'm running this on Windows Powershell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the three dots you return and only draw 1. But the 2 previous ones remain!

Just include (3-i) whitespaces after the dots

```
print ("Loading" + dot*i + ' '*(3-i), end = "\r")
```

By the way, a sleep of only 0.1 will make the dots very fast, try some bigger sleep for better visualization

Answer (score 1):

Your loop is continuing the way it should, but the periods from previous iterations aren't being erased or overwritten.

Printing some spaces after the periods should overwrite any text from the previous iteration:

```
print("Loading" + dot*i + "   ", end = "\r")
```